# Are noncommutative diagrams well defined?

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, group-isomorphism, morphism

A standard commutative diagram is the pictorial representation of the objects and morphisms within a given category. (This is the most general definition I can provide.)

A specific commutative diagram can be found by looking at morphisms which are group isomorphisms in the category $\textbf{Grp}$. Other examples exist and can be found in the textbook Category Theory for the Working Mathematician.

My question is this: can we define, in a rigorous manner, a noncommutative diagram? And, if we can, should we? What would such a concept be?

Note: I think this is worth considering because the breakdown of commutativity is always interesting to see in algebra.

Update: The user going by the name Daniel T. has addressed this question properly. However, Randall's answer in the comments also pinpoints that the notion of a noncommutative diagram is essentially silly and asinine in the notion of category theory. As such, I apologize for wasting time.

Comment: Are you looking for something different than the general category theory notion of a [diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagram_(category_theory))? A commutative diagram is just a diagram with an extra path-independence property that makes it "commutative".

Comment: If $g\circ h \neq f$ you have a noncommutative triangle.  Nothing about that is helpful or useful, though.

Comment: You mention your interest in commutativity in algebra.  Did you need to ask "can we define, in a rigorous manner, a noncommutative ring" (or "nonabelian group" if you prefer)?

Comment: @DanielHast and Randall, thank you very much for your feedback. I needed external guidance to comprehend the idea. rschwieb, thank you for your feedback. I am aware, vaguely, of noncommutative algebraic structures like you pointed out. Can you point me in the direction of a resource to learn more?

Comment: @Randall Thank you for your constructive feedback, and please have a pleasant day.

Comment: @rschwieb No. I was asking about noncommutative diagrams under the presumption that non commutativity translates into category theory as it does in algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A (not necessarily commutative) diagram is a functor $F:I\to \mathcal C$ where $I$ as a category with the shape you want (a triangle, a square, a rhombicosidodecahedron). Given morphisms $p:a\to b$, $q:b\to c$ and $r:a\to c$ we must have $F(g\circ f) = F(q)\circ F(p)$, but maybe $F(g\circ f) \neq F(h)$.

**Definition:**
A diagram is commutative if for all chains
$$
x\xrightarrow{f_0}
a_0\xrightarrow{}
\cdots \xrightarrow{f_n}
a_n
\xrightarrow{f_{n+1}}
y
$$
and
$$
x\xrightarrow{g_0}
b_0\xrightarrow{}
\cdots \xrightarrow{g_m}
b_n
\xrightarrow{g_{m+1}}
y
$$
in $\mathcal C$ then $g_{m+1}\circ \cdots g_0 = f_{n+1}\circ\cdots f_0$.
Otherwise it's a non-commutative diagram.

Comment: Does this mean that the morphisms compose properly in a commutative diagram and, in contrast, do not compose properly in a (theoretically defined) noncommutative diagram? Also, does this mean a noncommutative diagram would be essentially the same as two distinct and non equivalent chains (which is what I think you’re saying)?

Comment: In the categorical definition of a diagram you include the composites for all morphisms involved. Otherwise you just have a graph. To the second question: yes (sorta, by definition you just need two non-commuting chains to say that the whole diagram doesn't commute).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!

Comment: A rhombicosidodecahedron is a polytope, right? Or just a geometric solid?